# Add code to a parameter of a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add some code to a function that is passed as parameter to another function...
I have *funcA* wich receives *successCallback*, I need to append some code to that *successCallback* somehow...

Suppose this is *funcA*:

```
$.extend(ViewerFunction.prototype, {
        funcA : function(param1, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            //code
            if(successCallback)successCallback();
            //code  
        }
});
```

I'm trying to change funcA and pass a custom *successCallback*.
The code that I have written so far doesn't work:

```
    var old_function = ViewerFunction.funcA;
    ViewerFunction.funcA = function(param1, successCallback, errorCallback){

        var old_callback = successCallback;

        old_function(param1, function(){
            old_callback();
            //code that i need to insert
        }, errorCallback);
    }
```

Any ideias on how to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you can't directly modify `funcA` and `successCAllback`? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: And why is `funcA` first on an object, but then it becomes a variable?

Comment: It kind of looks like you're trying to add some sort of "after advice" to `successCallback`, per [Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_oriented_programming) (AOP) concepts.

Comment: And what exactly does not work? You are trying to intercept the function and from what I read it should work this way.

Comment: funcA is declared inside of 
`$.extend(ViewerFunction.prototype, {
funcA : function(param1, successCallback, errorCallback){//code}
});`

and the error that I'm getting is that "this is undefined" when funcA is called